# Azure PowerShell Download blob contents from container

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

I'm trying to download sme blob files from an azure storage account.

There are a mix of other containers and blockblobs in the parent container, I need to download just the blockblobs and not the other containers, I can't find a way of seperating them out, also I need to download some blobs from a conatiner within a container.

My code will download all the contents in the parent blob, including all sub containers.

```
  $sub = "MySub"
$staccname = "straccname1234"
$key = "sdcsecurekeythinghere"
$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $staccname ` 
         -StorageAccountKey $key
$cont = "data\download\files.001" ##the container includes other cntainers and subcontainers
$dest = "C:\blb-Downloads"
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $sub –Default
Set-AzureSubscription -Currentstaccname $staccname -SubscriptionName $sub
Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $cont -Context $ctx
$blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $cont  -Context $ctx
$blobs | Get-AzureStorageBlobContent –Destination $dest  -Context $ctx
```

There are approx 75 files in the parent blob and 123 files in data\downloads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the newer [Azure PowerShell Az module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-4.2.0), you can use [`Get-AzStorageBlob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstorageblob?view=azps-4.2.0) to list all the block blobs from the container, then use [`Get-AzStorageBlobContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstorageblobcontent?view=azps-4.2.0) to download the blobs.

As already shown by [@George Wallace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46735566/azure-powershell-download-blob-contents-from-container/46736676#46736676), we can use [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7) or its alias `?` to filter block blob types.

**Demo:**

```
$resourceGroup = "myResourceGroup"
$storageAccount = "myStorageAccount"
$container = "myContainerName"
$destination = "./blobs"

# Create destination directory if it doesn't exist
if (-not (Test-Path -Path $destination -PathType Container)) {
    New-Item -Path $destination -ItemType Directory
}

# Get storage account with container we want to download blobs from
$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -Name $storageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup

# Get all BlockBlobs from container
$blockBlobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $container -Context $storageAccount.Context 
    | Where-Object {$_.BlobType -eq "BlockBlob"}

# Download each blob from container into destination directory
$blockBlobs | Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Destination $destination -Force
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you not just run the following and limit it to BlockBlobs only?

```
Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $cont  -Context $ctx | ? {$_.BlobType -eq "BlockBlob"}
```

Comment: I don't think this would work. What OP is really looking for is a way to download blobs at the root of a container and not the blobs inside virtual folders inside that container.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
$storageaccountname = "jawadtestsaacc"
$sastoken = ""
$ContainerName = "access"

$Ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageaccountname -SasToken $sastoken

Get-AzStorageBlob -Container "$ContainerName" -Blob "Az.json" -Context $Ctx | Get-AzStorageBlobContent
or
Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Container "$ContainerName" -Blob "Az.json" -Context $Ctx
```